# JQuery click function only in current div

Tags: jquery, click

I have many DIV with multiple classes in a page just like this.

```
<div class="testlayer">
    <label for="test1"><input name="test" id="test1" value="1" class="checkvalue" type="checkbox"></label>
    <label for="test2"><input name="test" id="test2" value="2" class="checkvalue" type="checkbox"></label>
    <label for="test3"><input name="teat" id="test3" value="all" class="checkall" type="checkbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="testlayer">
    <label for="test11"><input name="test" id="test11" value="1" class="checkvalue" type="checkbox"></label>
    <label for="test21"><input name="test" id="test21" value="2" class="checkvalue" type="checkbox"></label>
    <label for="test31"><input name="teat" id="test31" value="all" class="checkall" type="checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

There is also a JQuery to uncheck all other checkboxes, if the "all"-checkbox is checked and the other way around.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
$(".checkall").click(function() {
$(".checkvalue").attr('checked', false);
});

$(".checkvalue").click(function() {
$(".checkall").attr('checked', false);
});
 });
```

And now my problem: If i check a checkbox in one `testlayer`, the checkboxes in all other divs with this class change the staus too.
But i only want to have the event on the current div in which the checkbox i clicked is located.

I think i have to define something with `(this)` but i don`t know how ... sorry for being a newb to JQuery and thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YmcqJ/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".checkall").click(function() {
$(this).closest('div').find(".checkvalue").attr('checked', false);
});

$(".checkvalue").click(function() {
$(this).closest('div').find(".checkall").attr('checked', false);
});
 });
```